# Angular - Get form groups which are changed their initial state

Tags: angular, forms

I have a `FormArray` which holds `FormGroups`. Below is the required part of code

```
public formGroups: FormGroup = new FormGroup({ items: new FormArray([]) });
public createFormGroup = (dataItem) =>
new FormGroup({
    atrributeId: new FormControl(dataItem.atrributeId),
    objectType: new FormControl(dataItem.objectType, Validators.required),
    attributeDisplayName: new FormControl(dataItem.attributeDisplayName, Validators.required),     
    dataType: new FormControl(dataItem.dataType, Validators.required),
    inputValues: new FormControl(dataItem.inputValues, [Validators.required,  InputValuesValidator]),
    isGridEligible: new FormControl(dataItem.isGridEligible, Validators.required),
    isInvoiceEligible: new FormControl(dataItem.isInvoiceEligible, Validators.required),
});

public editRows(grid) { 
  this.formGroups.markAllAsTouched();     
  this.isEdited = true;
  this.isDeleted = false;
  let currentRow = 0;
  let rows: any = grid.data.data;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    const formGroup = this.createFormGroup(rows[i]);          
    this.formGroup = formGroup;
    (this.formGroups.get('items') as FormArray).push(formGroup);        
    grid.editRow(currentRow, formGroup, {skipFocus: true});
    currentRow++;
    
      formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
        console.log(val);
      });
  }
}
```

How can I push only form groups which changes their initial values? Right now, when I see the console, it is being called all the times when I change any of the value in a editing row i.e., formgroup. I need to form an array with only edited rows. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Your code looks strange. Why do you generate FormGroups inside the editRow()-method? Don't you already have them? What is the main purpose of your code? Please, be more precise.

Comment: because I am enabling editing of a grid rows, whenever I click on editRows method, form groups will create for each row with data it holds.